# How to get a symbol looks like >---<

Tags: symbols, arrows

[image]

Please help me to input a symbol like `>---<`.

It is like `\leftrightarrow` but `\leftrightarrow` is `<--->`.

Comment: Look for 'to reversed-to reversed' in TikZ manual.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways:

1. with the `fdsymbol` package and some `mkern` trickery
2. with some `mkern` trickery and common symbols.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}

\newcommand{\doubleY}{\rightY\mkern-8mu\leftY\mkern5mu}

\newcommand{\doubletail}{>\mkern-10mu-\mkern-5mu-\mkern-10mu<}

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{fdsymbol}: $1\doubleY2$

Not using \texttt{fdsymbol}: $1\doubletail2$   

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Thank you. I adjusted the example.

Answer (score 2):

Or with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[>-<] (0,0) -- ++(1em, 0);\par
\tikz\draw[<->] (0,0) -- ++(1em, 0);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably OP like to have a command, which will draw this "doubletail" symbol :)